# Change node config without restarting?

Tags: config

Is it not clear to me if the command `config update` (https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html) will update the current config file and the node will then run using the new configuration without restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no configuration options which can be done "live". All config changes require a node restart.